# On paper = 'Sur le papier' ou 'en théorie'

Tags: traduction, anglais, anglicismes

> The design certainly looks good on paper.

> La conception semble certainement bonne sur le papier.

Sur le papier me semble un peu être un anglicisme. Est-ce mieux d'utiliser 'en théorie'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cette expression est parfaitement idiomatique et ne tient pas de l'anglicisme, sauf erreur de ma part.

Le deuxième sens du [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sur_le_papier#Locution_adverbiale) correspond à ton utilisation :

> *(Figuré)* Se dit, par opposition à effectif, réel ; en théorie.

Comment: Au Québec c'est employé sans l'article (_sur papier_), donc on est plus proche de la phraséologie anglophone, ou c'est par réduction typique, est-ce que ça en ferait un anglicisme ? Le TLFi a un exemple de Verlaine et en anglais ça semble être du 16e (avec _in_ d'abord dans OED1.).